# Zend, slow load, "waiting for response" for 20-80 seconds on local site

Tags: zend-framework

So I have several sites running under the same zend setup. All of the sites run pretty normally except one. Upon loading or reloading this one site, reguardless of which page your on (excluding the 404 page explanation later...) you get a serious pause before any content begins to download. Using firebugs net panel you can see that the first request which is www.(siteaddress).com.local you see a "waiting for response" bar (purple) that is going for anywhere from 20 to sometimes 80+ seconds and this isn't on a dev site, this is on a local site under localhost.

What I've managed to figure out so far is that all the pages do this except my 404 page. The reason the 404 page doesn't succumb to this is because it uses a seperate controller (the error controller) and therefore bypasses much of the controller and functions the other parts of the site use.

Using exit statements I've manged to figure out that the problem happens somewhere between my post dispatch and my main (top most) controllers Init function. If i exit in the main controllers init the page loads (then exits instantly, no wait). If i do the same in the pre or post dispatch the page waits the 20-80 seconds then exits.

Is there a diagram or explanation somewhere or a way for me to find out what events fire inbetween the post dispatch and the main controllers init function? Or does anyone have any clue what might cause this? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Question: after it takes a long time to reload, if you hit refresh, the page refreshes instantaneously or takes 20+ seconds again? Mine is the first case. I'm suspecting of SESSION locks (http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you check out http://devzone.zend.com/article/11978 which has an image of the loading process and links to a more detailed PDF at http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf

Out of interest is your application using a database at all that might be slowing things down?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this through a debugger?